# Can't using kotlin dependency in kotlin file

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, kotlin

I added `compile files('libs/(File Name).jar')` in `build.gradle`.

I cannot use it in `.kt`, but I can use it in `.java`.

**Java:**

[image: Tested in .java File]

**Kotlin:**

[image: Tested in .kt File]

**In (File Name).jar:**

[image: My Function in Kotlin]

Answer (score 0):

I found an issue seven months ago.
And I used Github + JitPack because I don't think it's going to be solved right away.